# Import Data From Excel & CSV to postgresql Using Codeigniter (skip insert row data inside excel file if 'program_id' already exist)

Tags: php, excel, postgresql, codeigniter

My project environment:-

- Codeigniter 3,
- postgresql 13,
- running with docker

Example from this [link](https://www.tutsmake.com/import-data-from-excel-csv-to-mysql-using-codeigniter/) will upload and insert the same data if you repeat the same action.

So I'm asking on how to prevent that by doing filter from certain field inside table.

in my case '*program_id*' is new field inside table with datatype **VARCHAR** and the '*program_id*' with its data inside **table** is [BM/21200, BM/21201, BM/21202].

Keep *id* as **PK** and **auto increment**.

So for example, I want to upload this excel file with '*program_id*' [BM/21200, BM/21201, BM/21202, BM/3000] and its respective data.

The result that I want. This application will insert only row data for [BM/3000] with its respective data and other *program_id* that doesn't exist inside DB table.

Now imagined that I have an Excel file with 1000 row of data and want to eliminate certain row inside excel file By *'program_id'* that already exist inside DB table. Maybe after doing filtration, only half row of data insert to the DB table.

All the help will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could create a table with a program_id column that is unique, read the data from the files with fgetcsv (csv) / phpspreadsheet (xlsx, xls) and do a INSERT IGNORE or INSERT ON  DUPLICATE.

Comment: Don't know if the syntax you've mentioned working or not in postgresql 13. Tried with my project & get syntax error.

Comment: I didn't know, but apparently the syntax for postgre is INSERT ON CONFLICT, https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-upsert/